# Image scale fitting whole screen without stretching

Tags: android

Im trying to make a splash screen with an image covering the whole layout, I have tried scale of 1.77 and 1.33 so far and failed to have the image successfully fitting in the screen without stretching. Any ideas what scale I should use

Answer (score 0):

Imageview has various scaletype tags that can be used.

Most of the time we use center crop tag to cover the whole view and maintaining the aspect ratio.

```
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

for different scaletypes follow below link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html